# Finding polygon parents

Tags: postgis

I have a PostGIS table full of polygon geometries.

Some of these polygons are contained inside other polygons in the same table.

I need to find which polygons have parents and self-relate them to their parent. How do I go about this?

Can I use `ST_Contains()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the table contains just two fields: id & the_geom, The following query could be used:

```
select a.id as child_id,b.id as parent_id from my_table a
join my_table b on ST_Contains(b.the_geom, a.the_geom) AND a.id != b.id;
```

The Join clause contains two things: Firstly if it checks if the `a.the_geom` is contained within `b.the_geom`, and secondly, makes sure that the parent_id & child_id are different.

The second part is required, because of the definition of [ST_Contains](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Contains.html)

> Returns true if and only if no points of B lie in the exterior of A,
>   and at least one point of the interior of B lies in the interior of A.

Comment: This is nearly perfect. Thanks! I'd also like to store this. How can I modify it to update the parent column?

Comment: you could make an update query which uses similar logic.

Comment: Got it with `update my_table a set parent = b.id from my_table b where ST_Contains(b.the_geom, a.the_geom) AND a.id != b.id;`